Image overlap when scroll down table view
I have the following code in cellForRow tableView function
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    
   if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0) {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
            
        
            let images = ["infographics3", "pintelquiz"]
            let imagesAdded : [String] = []
            
            // Initialize scrollView
            scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: tableView.bounds)
            scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
            scrollView.delegate = self
            scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
            
            // Set scrollView content size
            scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: tableView.bounds.width * CGFloat(images.count), height: 200)
            
            // Add images to scrollView
            for (index, imageName) in images.enumerated() {
                let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (CGFloat(index) * 345) + 10, y: 0, width: 337, height: 190))
                imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
                imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                
                scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
            }
            
            // Initialize pageControl
            pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: (tableView.bounds.width - 200)/2, y: 195, width: 200, height: 30))
            pageControl.numberOfPages = images.count
            pageControl.currentPage = 0
            pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = .lightGray
            pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .black
            
            cell.addSubview(scrollView)
            cell.addSubview(pageControl)
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            
            let selectedView = UIView()
            selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView
            
            return cell

When I scroll down the table view, the images in the cell get rendered again on top of previous images and create the screenshot attached. See attached.
Sometimes these images get rendered in the rows below instead of the first row.
Can someone help?


Every time the cell is reused, you are adding another scrollview on top of the existing one.

@Desdenova what can I do then?

I strongly suggest using a custom cell. And use func prepareForReuse() to clean your scroll view for the new images.

Btw, if you can change your code design, using a collection view with compositional layout would make this very easily in a modern way. Single view scrolling in both axis that is.

@Desdenova It's not working. Images are still overlapping.

We’d need to see your revised implementation to comment, but I agree with all of Desdenova’s observations. As an aside, the view debugger is really useful when diagnosing these issues; run the app on simulator or device and tap on the “view debugger” button, and it will show you the view hierarchy, at which point you can diagnose whether the problem is overlapping scroll views, overlapping image views, incorrect frames, etc.
